# How can I efficiently find the subset of activities that stay within a budget and maximizes utility?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, knapsack-problem

I am trying to develop an algorithm to select a subset of activities from a larger list. If selected, each activity uses some amount of a fixed resource (i.e. the sum over the selected activities must stay under a total budget). There could be multiple feasible subsets, and the means of choosing from them will be based on calculating the opportunity cost of the activities not selected.

---

**EDIT:** There are two reasons this is not the [0-1 knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#0-1_knapsack_problem):

- Knapsack requires integer values for the weights (i.e. resources consumed) whereas my resource consumption (i.e. mass in the knapsack parlance) is a continuous variable. (Obviously it's possible to pick some level of precision and quantize the required resources, but my bin size would have to be very small and Knapsack is `O(2^n)` in W.
- I cannot calculate the opportunity cost a priori; that is, I can't evaluate the fitness of each one independently, although I can evaluate the utility of a given set of selected activities or the marginal utility from adding an additional task to an existing list.

---

The research I've done suggests a naive approach:

> Define the [powerset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set)
>      For each element of the powerset, calculate it's utility based on the items not in the set
>      Select the element with the highest utility

However, I know there are ways to speed up execution time and required memory. For example:

- fully enumerating a powerset is `O(2^n)`, but I don't need to fully enumerate the list because once I've found a set of tasks that exceeds the budget I know that any set that adds more tasks is infeasible and can be rejected. That is if `{1,2,3,4}` is infeasible, so is `{1,2,3,4} U {n}`, where n is any one of the tasks remaining in the larger list.
- Since I'm just summing duty the order of tasks doesn't matter (i.e. if `{1,2,3}` is feasible, so are `{2,1,3}`, `{3,2,1}`, etc.).
- All I need in the end is the selected set, so I probably only need the best utility value found so far for comparison purposes.
- I don't need to keep the list enumerations, as long as I can be sure I've looked at all the feasible ones. (Although I think keeping the duty sum for previously computed feasible sub-sets might speed run-time.)

I've convinced myself a good recursion algorithm will work, but I can't figure out how to define it, even in pseudo-code (which probably makes the most sense because it's going to be implemented in a couple of languages--probably Matlab for prototyping and then a compiled language later).

Comment: unfortunately, this is NP-complete: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem so it's unlikely that you will find a fast algorithm.

Comment: This sounds exactly like the Knapsack problem to me. How is your problem different from the Knapsack problem? Please help me understand the difference, and we can talk about code (if it is the Knapsack problem, there is a lot of literature for it online).

Comment: @Henrik: You information is great, but note that the OP only want an exponential algo which is fine.

Comment: @Adam How large is the set? 2^n is HUGE, even after optimizing it could be terrible. Also, I find your problem similar to one that I've answered before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6629581/which-optimization-algorithm-should-i-use-for-maximizing-profit-with-time-limitat/6629641#6629641

Comment: Whether or not the OP wants a fast algorithm is irrelevant. If his problem is the Knapsack problem, a simple reading of Wikipedia and some links will say more than any of us could in a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: @Adam: Considering the last point of my answer, is there more context you can share about the problem? It might change the pool of answers quite a bit.

Comment: @Patrick87 It took me a while to figure it out, but my problem is different than the knapsack problem because my objects do not have integer weights or integer utilities/opportunity cost. I'm looking into whether I can bin them into buckets of integer weights, but I'm doubtful that will work without an excessively large number of buckets.

Answer (score 2):

The [knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) is NP-complete, meaning that there's no efficient way of solving the problem. However there's a pseudo-polynomial time solution using dynamic programming. See the [Wikipedia section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Dynamic_programming_solution) on it for more details.

However if the maximum utility is large, you should stick with an approximation algorithm. One such approximation scheme is to greedily select items that have the greatest utility/cost. If the budget is large and the cost of each item is small, then this can work out very well.

EDIT: Since you're defining the utility in terms of items not in the set, you can simply redefine your costs. Negate the cost and then shift everything so that all your values are positive.

Comment: pseudo-polynomial might work out just fine as the number of objects could be large (large `n`), but with respect to the number that are likely to fit into the budget at a given time, this is probably significantly more limited (i.e. I'm standing in Walmart with a really small backpack).

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, you are trying to solve some instance of the Knapsack problem. While theoretically, you are doomed, in practice you may still do a lot to increase the performance of your algorithm. Here are some (wildly assorted) ideas:

- **Be aware of [Backtracking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking).** This corresponds to your observation that once you crossed out `{1, 2, 3, 4}` as a solution, `{1, 2, 3, 4} u {n}` is not worth looking at.
- **Apply [Dynamic Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) techniques.**
- **Be clear about your actual requirements**:

  - Maybe you don't need the **best** set? Will a good one do? I am not aware if there is an algorithm which provides a good solution in polynomial time, but there might well be.
  - Maybe you don't need the best set **all the time**? Using randomized algorithms you can solve some `NP`-Problems in polynomial time with the risk of failure in 1% (or whatever you deem "safe enough") of all executions.

(Remember: It's one thing to know that the halting problem is not solvable, but another to build a program that determines whether "hello world" implementations will run indefinetly.)

Comment: you asked above but I don't understand your last parenthetical sentence at all. As for your question, I think what I have is classic 0-1 Knapsack. My problem may have large n, but a small budget so a pseudo-polynomial time implementation will probably work. I'll have to prototype on some sample data sets to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following iterative algorithm will traverse the entire solution set and store the list of tasks, the total cost of performing them, and the opportunity cost of the tasks not performed.

It seems like it will execute in pseudo-polynomial time: polynomial in the number of activities and exponential in the number of activities that can fit within the budget.

```
ixCurrentSolution = 1

initialize empty set solution {
    oc(ixCurrentSolution)        = opportunity cost of doing nothing
    tasklist(ixCurrentSolution)  = empty set
    costTotal(ixCurrentSolution) = 0
    }

for ixTask = 1:cActivities
    for ixSolution = 1:ixCurrentSolution 
        costCurrentSolution = costTotal(ixCurrentSolution) + cost(ixTask)
        if costCurrentSolution < costMax
             ixCurrentSolution++
             costTotal(ixCurrentSolution) = costCurrentSolution 
             tasklist(ixCurrentSolution)  = tasklist(ixSolution) U ixTask 
             oc(ixCurrentSolution)       = OC of tasks not in tasklist(ixCurrentSolution)
        endif
    endfor
endfor
```